# SQL Date normalisation and alignment

Tags: sql, datetime, calculation, calculated-field

Can someone help me please. I'm looking for the SQL calculation that will normalise my dates to this current year and align them to day for example:

Mon 01/01/2018 -> 30/12/19
Tues 02/01/18 -> 31/12/19

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two requirements, one is the calculation of a date, the second is the date display format, correct?

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

A solution in T-SQL for SQL Server:

Add 104 weeks to each date? (52 weeks per 2 years == 104 weeks)

```
select dateadd(WEEK,104,cast('01-01-2018' as date))
select dateadd(WEEK,104,cast('01-02-2018' as date))
```

returns

```
2019-12-30
2019-12-31
```

Comment: How do we account for leap years?